# Align labels in a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have difficulties with text alignment in pyplot. I am trying to annotate points arranged in a circular fashion in a circular dendrogram, so it is important that the labels are pointing away from the dots and keeping the right angle. Here is the relevant part of what I have so far.
[image: dots in a circle]

The horizontal labels work like a charm, but the vertical ones are obviously off. It seems that `horizontalalignment` / `verticalalignment` is applied on the original coordinates and on the bounding box. Is there any option / way to correctly align the labels without performing some crazy stunts like figuring out the text hight and moving the labels accordingly. I was wondering if it would make sense to overlay a second plot / axis with polar coordinates and put the text on it, but I am not sure if this will lead me anywhere. Or wether I am missing something really obvious...

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(fig, ax) = plt.subplots(figsize = (4,4))

def kex(N):
    alpha = 360. / N
    coordX = []
    coordY = []
    alphas = []
    for i in range(0,N):
        alpha_loop = alpha * i
        coordX.append( math.cos(math.radians(alpha_loop)) )
        coordY.append( math.sin(math.radians(alpha * i)) )
        alphas.append(alpha_loop)
    return [coordX, coordY, alphas]

N = 10
points = kex(N)
ax.scatter(points[0], points[1])
for i in range(0,N):
    x = points[0][i]
    y = points[1][i]
    a = points[2][i]
    if x > 0:
        ax.text(x + x * 0.1, y + y * 0.1, "AAA", rotation = a,
                    bbox=dict(facecolor = "none", edgecolor ="red"))
    else:
        ax.text(x + x * 0.1, y + y * 0.1, "AAA", rotation = a - 180,
                    bbox=dict(facecolor = "none", edgecolor ="red"), ha = "right")

ax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43894987/networkx-node-labels-relative-position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may offset the text enough not to have it overlap with the points. The idea is then to center-align (`ha="center", va="center"`) the text, such that will be sitting on an extended (virtual) line between the graph's midpoint and the dot it annotates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

(fig, ax) = plt.subplots(figsize = (4,4))

def kex(N):
    alpha=2*np.pi/N
    alphas = alpha*np.arange(N)
    coordX = np.cos(alphas)
    coordY = np.sin(alphas)

    return np.c_[coordX, coordY, alphas]

N = 10
r = 1.2
points = kex(N)
ax.scatter(points[:,0], points[:,1])

for i in range(0,N):
    a = points[i,2] 
    x,y = (r*np.cos(a), r*np.sin(a))
    if points[i,0] < 0: a = a - np.pi
    ax.text(x,y, "AAA", rotation = np.rad2deg(a), ha="center", va="center",
                    bbox=dict(facecolor = "none", edgecolor ="red"))

ax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

[image]