# Placing text around the circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using pyplot `circle` function I made a circle, then I have used `text` function to place the text(parameters) across the circle(PLOT ATTACHED) but the thing is if let's say I want to list out only 6 or say 11 parameters equally spaced across the circle I'll have to chage the coordinates as well as the rotation in `text`(and the coordinates and rotation value has been manually set). I want something that'll automate these things like given a number of parameter it will place parameter with equal spacing between them around the circle

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 20))
ax.axis('equal')

ax.set(xlim=(-10, 23), ylim = (-10, 10))

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 4.7, fc='#cfe2f3')
ax.add_patch(circle)

ax.text(-0.4, 4.9, 'npxG', fontsize=15)
ax.text(3.35, 3.5, 'xA', rotation=310, fontsize=15)
ax.text(4.8, -0.5, 'Shots on Target', rotation=270, fontsize=15)
ax.text(3.35, -3.55, 'Dribbles', rotation=50, fontsize=15)
ax.text(-1, -5., 'Through Balls', fontsize=15)
ax.text(-4.6, -3.6, 'Passes 1/3', rotation=305, fontsize=15)
ax.text(-5, -0.5, 'Key Passes', rotation=90, fontsize=15)
ax.text(-4., 3.3, 'Crosses', rotation=42, fontsize=15)

ax.axis('off')
```

[image]

Edit:

```py
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    a = points[i,2] 
    x,y = (radius*np.sin(a), radius*np.cos(a))
    a = a - 0.5*np.pi
    if points[i,1] < 0:
      a = a - np.pi 
    ax.text(x, y, data[i], rotation = np.rad2deg(a), ha="center", va="center", fontsize=15)
```

On changing order of the array:
[image]

On flipping the x and y values:
[image]

Comment: Please add code to your question to provide an MVCE.

Comment: Question has been updated with added code and plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using code and inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43919803/align-labels-in-a-circle-in-matplotlib) question and answer and a bit of coordinate geometry:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 20))
ax.axis('equal')

ax.set(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 2.7, fc='#cfe2f3')
ax.add_patch(circle)

def kex(N):
    alpha=2*np.pi/N
    alphas = alpha*np.arange(N)
    coordX = np.cos(alphas)
    coordY = np.sin(alphas)

    return np.c_[coordX, coordY, alphas]


data = ["npxG", "xA", "Shots on Target", "Dribbles", "Through Balls", 
        "Passes 1/3", "Key Passes", "Crosses"]
radius = 3.2
points = kex(len(data))

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    a = points[i,2] 
    x,y = (radius*np.cos(a), radius*np.sin(a))
    if points[i,0] < 0:
      a = a - np.pi
    ax.text(x, y, data[i], ha="center", va="center", fontsize=15)

ax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

Gives this:

[image: first]

If you wish to adapt something like the linked answer and rotate the labels as a perpendicular to the circle, change this line:

```
ax.text(x, y, data[i], rotation = np.rad2deg(a), ha="center", va="center", fontsize=15)
```

Note the added `roatation` parameter. This gives:

[image: second]

To adapt something like the sample image in the question:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    a = points[i,2] 
    x,y = (radius*np.cos(a), radius*np.sin(a))
    a = a - 0.5*np.pi
    if points[i,1] < 0:
      a = a - np.pi
    ax.text(x, y, data[i], rotation = np.rad2deg(a), ha="center", va="center", fontsize=15)
```

This gives:

[image: third]

The list `data` can be populated with label text. On changing the number of labels, the plot should adapt accordingly. The parameter `radius` adjusts the distance of the text from the center of the circle. You can add in extra parameters to the `.text()` function such as `fontsize` as required for the labels.

Note: View this answer on the SO white theme to see the labels clearly. I took the liberty to change the plot size to fit it here. Huge thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the linked question's answer.

Comment: Hey, I now have flipped the x and y values so that the lables are shown by their order in the given data-list, like npxG will come at top then xA so on so forth. But as i am flipping the x and y values the rotations does not seems to work, can you tell me the intuition behind the rotation part? I have added the code can you please check it out.

Comment: Have you find something??

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by flipping x and y values. Please ask a new question with a [mcve]

Comment: What I did was assigned the radius\*sin(a) value to x and radius\*cos(a) value to y, so that the parameters align in such a way that at the top of the circle the first paramter is placed(which in my case is npxG). The code that you wrote was placing npxG at the right not at the top. You can see the plot as well as the code(attached in the question after the Edit). I hope you get it.

Comment: Why would you do that? Instead just change the order of the array.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing the order of the array and yes it was giving me the result. But by flipping the axis I am getting the desired result as you can see in the question(updated), like you can see how npxG is now at top of the circle but only problem is the rotation part. I hope you get it.

Comment: Have you got something?