# Python: Rotation value for text placed around the circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the code snippet:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 20))
ax.axis('equal')

ax.set(xlim=(-10, 10), ylim=(-10, 10))

circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 3.1, fc='cyan')
ax.add_patch(circle)

def kex(N):
    alpha=2*np.pi/N
    alphas = alpha*np.arange(N)
    coordX = np.cos(alphas)
    coordY = np.sin(alphas)

    return np.c_[coordX, coordY, alphas]

data = 'P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 P11 P12 P13 P14'.split(' ')
radius = 3.3
points = kex(len(data))

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    a = points[i,2] 
    x,y = (radius*np.sin(a), radius*np.cos(a))
    
    a = a - 0.5*np.pi
    
    if points[i, 1] < 0:
        a = a - np.pi
    
    ax.text(x, y, data[i], rotation=np.rad2deg(a), ha="center", va="center", fontsize=15)
    
ax.axis("off")

plt.show()
```

I want to place the text around a circle but does not seem to find correct rotation values. Some code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156291/placing-text-around-the-circle) I have tweaked some bits in the code but does not seem to find the correct rotation values. Can someone help?

Output is:
[image]

Edit 01:

I want something like this screenshot taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63156291/placing-text-around-the-circle).

[image]

Comment: Your radius is 3.3 instead of 3.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say exactly what your intended output should be. If its that the bottom of each text label lines up with the tangent of the circle, you are almost there; you can do this:

```
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    a = points[i,2] 
    x,y = (radius*np.sin(a), radius*np.cos(a))
       
    ax.text(x, y, data[i], rotation=-np.rad2deg(a), ha="center", va="center", fontsize=15)
```

i.e. remove the lines of code which modify `a` after you calculate `x` and `y`, and then use minus the angle `a` to set the rotation of the text.

[image]

To answer the edited question, you can simply use:

```
    if y < 0:
        a += np.pi
```